# IOS - Create new object instances through a loop with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, instance

Basically, my problem is that I'm trying to create 3 instances of a UIView through a loop. I'm using ARC and I don't really know  if what I want to do is possible with it. Here's the code I currently have :

```
NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RoomView"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil];
NSMutableArray *roomViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[gtb.rooms count]];

for (i = 0; i < [gtb.rooms count]; i++)
{
    RoomView *rcv = [[RoomView alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *room = [gtb.rooms objectAtIndex:i];
    rcv = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Start rcv = %@", rcv);
    rcv.roomNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chambre %d", i + 1];
    rcv.roomType.text = [room objectForKey:@"roomType"];
    [rcv setFrame:CGRectMake(0, sizeOfContent, rcv.frame.size.width, rcv.frame.size.height)];
    sizeOfContent += rcv.frame.size.height;
    [roomViews addObject:rcv];
    NSLog(@"End rcv = %@", rcv);
}

for (i = 0; i < [gtb.rooms count]; i++)
    NSLog(@"Room #%i : %@", i, [roomViews objectAtIndex:i]);
```

And here's what I have in the logs :

```
2012-09-20 10:15:00.287 AppName[2792:707] Start rcv = <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 0; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
2012-09-20 10:15:00.289 AppName[2792:707] End rcv = <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 420; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
2012-09-20 10:15:00.312 AppName[2792:707] Start rcv = <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 420; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
2012-09-20 10:15:00.314 AppName[2792:707] End rcv = <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 527; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
2012-09-20 10:15:00.316 AppName[2792:707] Start rcv = <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 527; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
2012-09-20 10:15:00.317 AppName[2792:707] End rcv = <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 634; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
2012-09-20 10:15:00.319 AppName[2792:707] Room #0 : <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 634; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
2012-09-20 10:15:00.323 AppName[2792:707] Room #1 : <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 634; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
2012-09-20 10:15:00.325 AppName[2792:707] Room #2 : <RoomView: 0x148570; frame = (0 634; 320 107); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x148510>>
```

I know if I wasn't using ARC, I should have placed something like `[rcv autoRelease]` at the end of the loop, but with ARC, I can't.

Is there any solution to solve it, or must I disable ARC for this file ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't see you creating any instances of UIView in the loop. The instances are apparently created when you call `loadNibNamed:`. They just get passed from `nibViews` to `roomViews`.

Comment: I've edited my post. But it seems that when I add the object to my Array, all the objects takes the properties of the last one.

Comment: Oh, that is because you're calling `[nibViews objectAtIndex:0]` instead of `[nibViews objectAtIndex:i]`.

Comment: Also, what are you doing with the `NSDictionary` `room`? It looks like it is never used.

Comment: I can't really call `[nibViews objectAtIndex:i]` because I only have one object in the Array. Maybe I understood something wrong, but I want to create 3 different instances of the same view. with the `NSDictionary *room`, I fill some of my view's variables. I didn't show it in the code since I didn't think it was really necessary.

Comment: It seems that somewhere you need to set the properties of `rcv` based on `room`.

Comment: I've posted the whole code, and what I get in the logs to show you exactly what I have.

Comment: As you can see, in the first loop the `origin.y` is correctly set (first 420, then 527, then 634). But in the second loop, they're all at 634.

Comment: The value of `rcv` is getting overwritten when you call `rcv = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0]`.

Comment: How could I avoid this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16910/discussion-between-tsabz-and-thomasw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this line:

```
rcv = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
```

With this one:

```
rcv = [[nibViews objectAtIndex:0] copy];
```

Because if not, you just are accessing the same view object, not a new one copied from it (strong reference not copied).

And as a side not, there is no influence of ARC in that matter. You would have same problem without ARC. With ARC you are just not writing release/autorelease etc.

Comment: Got this error : ` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RoomView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x24b1c0'`

Comment: My mistake, UIViews may not implement the copy method. You should override it in your custom class, to copy values you are interested in. Another (inefficient) way is to load nib every time inside the loop, calling [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RoomView"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: This inefficient way works in my case. Why do you call it inefficient ?

Comment: Because you potentially read from disk all the time, by loading the same content. It's slower than copying in-memory objects.

Answer (score 1):

With ARC, autorelease is being called for you. You don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

By the rule of memory management, you need to release only the objects you alloc-init or copy. Here you are not doing both with RoomView *rcv. 
So even if your code is `not ARC enabled` you need not release or autorelease it.